# mean and as.numeric functions not working

Tags: r, mean, analysis

I'm just starting out with R and I'm practicing basic analysis with flight data. One of the columns in this df is the number of minutes a given flight was delayed. I tried finding the average using `mean()` but it's returning the error:

> "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Obviously, this means this data is stored as something other than numbers; however, I've used `as.numeric` to change it to numbers (with no errors) and I used the `str()` function to verify that it's numbers and yet `mean()` is still not working. The weirdest part is that when I use the `summary()` function, it gives me the mean of that column! So R must know that there are numbers there! What is going on??

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
Origin Dest  DelayMinutes
chr    chr   dbl
JFK    FLL   5        
LAS    LAX   1
```

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your data, can only make speculations. Try to provide a snippet

Comment: heres' the full chunk or whatever:

 delta_flights %>%
+     mean("ArrDelay")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(., "ArrDelay") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @preston Jahi was referring to providing some of your data. You can type `dput(head(delta_flights)`  into the console, then you can paste the results into your question.

Comment: @AndrewGB I see! Just tried it. It doesn't paste well so I edited a bit so it'd be clear. Otherwise it was a scramble of letters/numbers

Comment: @preston That's actually what we need as it will preserve the structure as you have it. Just when you paste it into your question, then you will want to highlight it, then click the `{}` , which will format it as code. You can see what I did with my edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this column has NA values, so when you calculate the mean with mean() function you need to pass the na.rm = TRUE argument

```
mean(x, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: `mean()` will return NA in that case, not an error as OP mentioned.

Comment: That might be the solution, except now I'm getting an error that the object was not found. So confused seeing as when I run the summary function the column is clearly there (not to mention I can filter and create a new df using only that column :/

Comment: @AbdurRohman that's exactly what's happening. In fact, I created a new dataframe with the NA options filtered out and it's still giving me the original error

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, as you are essentially trying to get the mean of a string (e.g.,, `mean("string")`). So, you need to either get the mean of the column in base R or if you are wanting to use `dplyr`, then you need to use `mutate`.

So in base R, you could write like:

```
mean(delta_flights[,"DelayMinutes"], na.rm = T)
#[1] 3

# Or like this:
mean(delta_flights$DelayMinutes, na.rm = T)
#[1] 3
```

With `dplyr`, we could write like this to pipe into `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

delta_flights %>% 
  mutate(x = mean(DelayMinutes, na.rm = T))
```

**Output**

```
  Origin Dest DelayMinutes x
1    JFK  FLL            5 3
2    LAS  LAX            1 3
```

So, now if you can see that the results are the same as what you get with `summary()`:

```
summary(delta_flights)

 #   Origin              Dest            DelayMinutes
 #Length:2           Length:2           Min.   :1    
 #Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:2    
 #Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :3    
 #                                      Mean   :3    
 #                                      3rd Qu.:4    
 #                                      Max.   :5
```

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful. One last question: is mutating necessary? I now have a column where every value is the average of the delay minutes. I don't understand why that would be desired, as opposed to R just spitting out the mean

Comment: @preston I just added the `dplyr` option since you had the `%>%` in the comment above. But it really just depends on people's needs. For example, if you wanted to know if there were greater delays for different origin airports, then you might want to group by that column to see how the mean is different. But you would probably want to just use `summarise` in that case instead of `mutate`.